# State diagram Implementation

Tags: design, modeling

I am trying to develop a state machine model for my current firmware design. I searched google, but the explanations are not related to embedded system. Can you please suggest some method to study state diagram development for embedded systems.

Comment: I'm giving some [links](http://pm.ethz.ch/people/darvas/papers/DMB02.pdf) to you. Go through these link and you may get an idea how to make the state diagram for your design.

Comment: @Korkut:Definately i'll agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really enough information in your question to know what kind of state machine we are talking about as the terminology is very generic.

If we are talking a sequential logic system implemented using either discrete logic or FPGAs then you might want to search for Moore Model, Meely Model or Algorithmic State Machine. All these can be implemented using a clocked state register and logic. Many hardware descriptions compile down to these kind of approaches. With a more complete description I could give better advice.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are familiar with the basics of [state machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) (Wikipedia's diagram of a toaster oven is a simple example), I would strongly recommend one of [Miro Samek's books](http://books.google.com/books?id=D2RoQpixMfsC) on hierarchical state-charts, as it is very practical.

Here are some online links:

- http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~lee/06cse480/lec-HSM.pdf
- http://drdobbs.com/184401643